# Enabling Silverlight Out-of-browser breaks in-browser application

Tags: c#, silverlight, out-of-browser

I am currently developing a small application in Silverlight, and recently to try it out, i enabled out-of-browser deployment for my application.  However, now after I disabled the setting, running the application now throws an exception as soon as it finishes loading.

An unhandled exception ('Unhandled Error in silverlight application
Code: 4004
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.

However, if I just open the TestPage.html in browser the application still works as it did.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: That is odd! Have you tried setting a break point at the start of your silverlight code and seeing if you can get a line at which it fails?

Comment: I did, and got the error in App.xaml.cs just after the constructor.

I created a new silverlight project and copied all the .xaml and .cs over, and it works like normal again. Still would be interested to find the problem.

Comment: Post the InnerException of this exception.  That's what really went wrong.

Comment: An error occured while trying to make a request to URI '(my wcf service)'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to public a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.  This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibletoAttribute attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I'm not sure why activating out-of-browser and then going back required this, but adding a ClientAccessPolicy.xml file to the .web project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For example, Try entering the following line in the Application_UnhandledException method of App.Xaml.cs (the code-behind of the App.Xaml)
*"MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.Message);"*.  This could give you an idea what goes wrong when the debugger is not yet attached the browser. Buy the way, In Visual Studio you can attach the debugger manually to your browser in the debug menu -> Attach to Process..., then choose the process with type "Silverlight, x86" for example.

```
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.Message);
        // If the app is running outside of the debugger then report the exception using
        // the browser's exception mechanism. On IE this will display it a yellow alert 
        // icon in the status bar and Firefox will display a script error.
        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {

            // NOTE: This will allow the application to continue running after an exception has been thrown
            // but not handled. 
            // For production applications this error handling should be replaced with something that will 
            // report the error to the website and stop the application.
            e.Handled = true;
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { ReportErrorToDOM(e); });
        }
    }
```